# Typescript :: Conditional chaining function

Tags: typescript, chaining

I'm trying to implement a set of chained function but somehow I get stuck here.

```
interface ISimpleCalculator {
  plus(value: number): this;
  minus(value: number): this;
  divide(value: number): this;
  multiply(value: number): this;
  sum(): void
}

interface ISpecialCalculator extends ISimpleCalculator {
  specialPlus(value: number): ISimpleCalculator;
  specialMinus(value: number): ISimpleCalculator;
}

let testCalculator: ISpecialCalculator;
testCalculator  
  .plus(20)
  .multiply(2)
  .specialPlus(40)  
  .plus(20)
  .minus(5)
  .specialMinus(20)  //<-- Error! Property 'specialMinus' does not exist on type 'ISimpleCalculator'.
  .sum()
```

I want to archive type check of the function in the chain. In the above example, I want the functions `specialPlus` and `specialMinus` in `ISpecialCalculator` to be used once only and `ISimpleCalculator` can be used for multiple times. I'm pretty fresh to the typescript and  I've been trying different approaches (Advanced type (`Pick` & `Omit`)) with no success so far. I want to know is there any other way to help in this case.

Comment: I don't think this is possible in typescript, you will need javascript runtime implementation for such functionality

Comment: Imo you have to implment a concrete class, then it is working fine: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIGVgFsAOAbCAYTjwQFc84wB7KZAbwChll8yBnACgDcSyIAXMhBksAI2gBKIWAAWwdgG5GAX0aNQkWIhQYcEBMBLFSFKrWQQAHpBAATdmky4CJ8pRp0mLdvsMkABTwOHj5BYVEJKGknbHwiEndzKGU1RgRKdkcAFQh2MDdkOIIsCHBHPQMjPDczTwZmFlYoYF5IZF5g8JFxaAAfMnsIGFAIO2Um5taqFF8qkgA1EiEeqIGhkZAx5UaWNi5O-hXIqQZkOQUAOkOUAF4OsMVkKAgwMigQc-klZBUJprm-jwQRCN2OvWiZwu7EugOqSzwyHuNyeLzeHy+Cief1U6gIYHOeQKiTqtCElSBtQ8FnuWwA7shcvk3JxJMpIMySdSoLtkJd9pwAEwABkkvNhfmqIK4IrFk35wS4AGZRYogA

Comment: Hi @r3dst0rm, actually it's the same result. Don't forget the `ISpecialCalculator` interface contains of more than one function and each of them is allowed to be used once only.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Removing the some functions is simple, you can just use `Omit<this, 'specialPlus'>` If we test this it almost works, if you call `specialPlus` you will get an error if you call it immediately after another call to `specialPlus`, you can however call it after a call to  `specialMinus`

```
interface ISpecialCalculator extends ISimpleCalculator {
  specialPlus(value: number): Omit<this, 'specialPlus'>;
  specialMinus(value: number): Omit<this, 'specialMinus'>;
}

declare let testCalculator: ISpecialCalculator;
testCalculator  
  .specialPlus(40)
   // .specialPlus(40) // error 
  .specialMinus(20)
  .specialPlus(40) //ok 
  .sum()
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIGVgFsAOAbCAYTjwQFc84wB7KZAbwFgAoZZfMgZwAoA3EshABcyEGSwAjaAEoRYABbBOAbhZssoLnwHDR4qVFnIFS1a2QATYL2AWI2vIJFjJMuYpVrkWCmGD4ATwcnPVdDd1MvTnFuI15qWxYAXxYWUEhYRBQMHAgEYBJiUgoqWmQIAA9IEAtONExcAiLySho6JnNOXPySAAVHHn5HXRcDIwB5DTAAHhNOABpkAHIuvIK8fq4lgD4zNlWevABZTUGdZ303ZEngGbnFle71k7FOHbMU5hY7BEooFAIYGMEE4YGaJTaIhya0KJBapSgZkgoPBrTKbC8ADoDutNjwACwABmkWJxfQG3CJ0mQAHoaeUoFBaKSniQXloAEzElkwjYUqm0mnUADWyCE3FJMWkQA)

This is because `Omit` will work on the `this` type bound when `testCalculator` is declared, so `specialMinus` will return in fact `Omit<ISpecialCalculator, 'specialMinus'>` which will still contain `specialPlus` even though we previously removed it. What we want is for `Omit` to work on the type of `this` returned by the previous function. We can do this if we capture the actual type of `this` for each call using a generic type parameter, and `Omit` methods from this type parameter not from polymorphic `this`.

```
interface ISimpleCalculator {
  plus<TThis>(this: TThis,value: number): TThis;
  minus<TThis>(this: TThis,value: number): TThis;
  divide<TThis>(this: TThis,value: number): TThis;
  multiply<TThis>(this: TThis,value: number): TThis;
  sum(): void
}

interface ISpecialCalculator extends ISimpleCalculator {
  specialPlus<TThis>(this: TThis, value: number): Omit<TThis, 'specialPlus'>;
  specialMinus<TThis>(this: TThis, value: number): Omit<TThis, 'specialMinus'>;
}

declare let testCalculator: ISpecialCalculator;
testCalculator
  .specialPlus(40)
  // .specialPlus(40) // error 
  .specialMinus(20)
  .plus(10)
  .specialPlus(40) // also error 
  .plus(10)
  .sum()
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIGVgFsAOAbCAYTjwQFc84wB7KZAbwFgAoZZfMgZwB4AVXgBbBOAPgAUYIZwBcyflIA0ANxJkIskGSwAjaAEpZ84QG4WbLKC59Bw8ZOGGbnZavXJNO-Y6mnWyACbASsD+ENZSdlLewi54ahpaulAGck7GyGbIWBRgwPgAnuG2ElGpiipxbh5JKUacvmycWmIpStQhLAC+LCygkLCIKBg4EAjAJMSkFFS0yBAAHpAg-pxomLgEk+SUNHRMfpwjYyQACnE8dZEOZTHIFfHuiV7IAPIWYEXOyADkh6PjeDOXG+IgayD+xzwAFlLBcnFcZDcvvcqk9krI3sAPnUFD8IQCYZpOCDfN1mCxQghKFAUAQwMhIJwwFtprtZMN-hMSNsZlBfIzmdzWbRMgA6fGnc5iAAsAAY9JkAPSK5Dio4AoGcGXy5DKuZQKCzQA8G4BI-bFEuhsLEACZ5WKOFqAIx2vxqzmAqVyvS6lUkTjUfWGuim+1S50K11NLAtIA)

Comment: Hi @Titian, I have tried the same approach as yours before. Just like what you said, it's "almost" works :) but don't forget we still can add in `plus` `minus` ... in between of  `specialPlus` & `specialMinus`.

Comment: @NelsonTang wops, my bad. Fixed. You need to apply the same generic treatment to the other functions as well just that they return `TThis`

Comment: OH!!!! I JUST GET IT! You are so right! What I want is `this` returned by the previous function. I've underestimated the power of `this`. You have saved my day master @Titian!

Answer (score 1):

```
specialPlus(value: number): ISimpleCalculator;
```

When you call this function, you are getting back a simple calculator that doesn't have the special functions anymore. The special interface should also return `this` and it should be working:

```
interface ISpecialCalculator extends ISimpleCalculator {  
   specialPlus(value: number): this;
   specialMinus(value: number): this;
}
```

Comment: Hi @amit, the reason I put `ISimpleCalculator` is that I want to limit the functions in `ISpecialCalculator` to be used once only.

Answer (score -1):

Try the following (full code tested based on the question):

```
interface ISimpleCalculator {
  plus(value: number): this
  minus(value: number): this
  divide(value: number): this
  multiply(value: number): this
  sum(): void
}

interface ISpecialCalculator extends ISimpleCalculator {
  specialPlus(value: number): this
  specialMinus(value: number): this
}

let testCalculator: ISpecialCalculator
testCalculator
  .plus(20)
  .multiply(2)
  .specialPlus(40)
  .plus(20)
  .minus(5)
  .specialMinus(20) 
  .sum()
```

If you want to limit the ***special[Plus|Minus]*** usage then you can accomplish that in the concrete class that implements the *ISpecialCalculator* interface.

The code below may give you some ideas:

```
class Calculator implements ISpecialCalculator {
  specialPlusUsed = false
  specialMinusUsed = false

  specialPlus(value: number): this {
    if (this.specialPlusUsed) throw new Error("SpecialPlus can be used only once!")

    this.specialPlusUsed = true
    // Related calculations here...
    return this
  }

  specialMinus(value: number): this {
    if (this.specialMinusUsed) throw new Error("SpecialMinus can be used only once!")
    this.specialMinusUsed = true
    // Related calculations here...
    return this
  }

  plus(value: number): this {
    // Related calculations here...
    return this
  }

  minus(value: number): this {
    // Related calculations here...
    return this
  }

  divide(value: number): this {
    // Related calculations here...
    return this
  }

  multiply(value: number): this {
    // Related calculations here...
    return this
  }

  sum(): void {
    // Related calculations here...
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi Ben Dev, your answer is the same as above @amit. The function in `ISpecialCalculator` is allowed to be used only once.

Comment: @NelsonTang interfaces define a contract, you cannot limit how many times they will be used within the application!

Comment: @NelsonTang take a look at the sample code that implements the "ISpecialCalculator" interface. Hope that helps.

Comment: Hi @BenDev, I fully understand at your approach but what I'm trying to achieve is blocking the user through the type guard, not at runtime.